# Create an application under default web site IIS

Tags: c#, iis

I am trying to create a new application under default web site by using C# code. This is what I tried

```
public static bool CreateWebSite(Application application)
    {
        try
        {
            application.Alias = "Test";
            application.PhysicalPath = @"C:\Test";
            application.ApplicationPool = "TestAppPool";
            using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
            {
                serverManager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications.Add("/", application.PhysicalPath);
               serverManager.CommitChanges();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception se)
        {
            throw se;
        }
    }
```

But getting `path already exists` error can some one help me.

Comment: You cannot add an application whose path is `/`, because that's the root application of a site (created automatically when the site was created). Try `/Test`.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li how can I add the application pool for the same instead of default app pool i need to set my own

Comment: Ok got it after creating the application I set it

Comment: How can we set directory browsing enabled?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site for tutorials. Microsoft has a documentation site for that purpose and every setting comes with C# sample code, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

> How can we set directory browsing enabled

You could try to use below command to set directory browsing enabled.

```
        ServerManager server = new ServerManager();

        Configuration config = server.GetWebConfiguration("TestMVC");

        ConfigurationSection directoryBrowseSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/directoryBrowse");
        directoryBrowseSection["enabled"] = true;
        directoryBrowseSection["showFlags"] = @"Date, Time, Size, Extension";

        server.CommitChanges();
```

Result:

[image]